# how to get below output using awk or sed

Tags: awk

I have file with below data

```
XXX  10/24/2013  07:31:02 10/24/2013  07:32:16 abc 913357/1
xxx  -----                -----                bbc 913357/3
xxx  -----                10/23/2013  19:10:48 abc 912211/10 -ddd
```

how to get only below output

```
abc
bbc
abc
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming those columns are tab separated:

```
awk -F\t print{$6} inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

Comment: Will not work if its used space

Answer (score 1):

How many different ways can you think of?  Assuming your file is called `data`:

```
cut -c 48-50 data

sed 's/^.\{47\}\(...\).*/\1/' data

awk '{ print substr($0, 48, 3) }' data
```

You can't easily do it using fields because there are 7 fields in both the first and last sample lines, but you need to print field 5 or 6, depending on which of the two lines it is.